# MYSQL Joining operations in the same table

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT mp.Group_Name FROM measurement_test mt, measurement_point mp, measurement_values mv 
                        WHERE mt.Test_ID = mv.Test_ID AND mv.Point_ID = mp.Point_ID AND mt.ID_Number = 'WR20120603_05' 


SELECT DISTINCT mp.Group_Name FROM measurement_test mt, measurement_point mp, measurement_values mv 
                        WHERE mt.Test_ID = mv.Test_ID AND mv.Point_ID = mp.Point_ID AND mt.ID_Number = 'WR20120603_04'
```

Above are the two queries that i am using in my web page. Actually i want to get only the common group_name values of the results between the two queries, Is there any other posssible way to implement this particular scenario, or simplyfying the above two queries?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT mp.Group_Name 
FROM measurement_test mt
inner join measurement_values mv on mt.Test_ID = mv.Test_ID
inner join measurement_point mp on mv.Point_ID = mp.Point_ID
WHERE mt.ID_Number in ('WR20120603_04', 'WR20120603_05')
group by mp.Group_Name
having count(distinct mt.ID_Number) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it using `IN` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mp.Group_Name 
FROM    measurement_test mt
            INNER JOIN measurement_point mp
                ON mt.Test_ID = mp.Test_ID
            INNER JOIN measurement_values mv 
                ON mv.Point_ID = mp.Point_ID
WHERE   mt.ID_Number IN ('WR20120603_05', 'WR20120603_04')
GROUP BY    mp.Group_Name 
HAVING      COUNT(mp.Group_Name) = 2
```

Comment: That will return `id_number`s that are either. But OP wants common ones.